# How to implement real-time sound notification in Reactjs and Laravel?

Tags: reactjs, laravel-5.8

I have to design a **restaurant's order-taking and kitchen system**.  When an order is confirmed by a waiter, the order details must **appear realtime in the kitchen computer on kitchen user's login and a buzzer sound should keep beeping** until kitchen user clicks on order id (ie. to accept or reject the order).

I am using Laravel for API endpoint and Reactjs for the front end design and MySql database.

Please let me know how can I achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

You have two ways to implement this one an old way "pulling model" ask on the client side each n seconds "is where any new notifications"?
Or use websokets to constantly holed contention with your client. 
You will need to write worker on php or on NodeJs that will hold websokets connections with client.

Also a heard that there are third party services can help send notices to your clients. Like this one  https://pusher.com.

Comment: Shall come back once implementation is done, or at least tried your or some other solution!